# Why isn't my Spree::User record updating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, spree, spree-auth-devise

I started a new project on **Spree 3.0.1** and I have to implement a gift card system that binds a certain amount of store credit to a user when a gift card is claimed. Given that as of version 3.0.1 the store credits functionality has not been implemented I'm trying to implement a simple system myself.

I ran a migration to add a column to **Spree::User** indicating the amount of store credit they have. Also added was a new step on the checkout process where a user can choose to use some or all of the store credit that is available. This step generates a price adjustment reducing the price of the order. A field was also created on **Spree::Order** to store how much of the store credit is being used on the transaction.

So far this has been done without much trouble. The real trouble comes when I'm trying to update the credit that the user has left. I have this code in my order_decorator.rb

```
Spree::Order.state_machine.after_transition to: :complete, do: :update_user_credit

def update_user_credit
  credit_used = self.credit_used
  initial_credit = self.user.credit
  self.user.update(credit: initial_credit - credit_used)
end
```

To update the store credit I run an callback after the order is completed, updating the credit of the user. For some reason this instruction is never executed.

Updating the user credit from the console has been done. The user is accessible from the callbacks, since I have used the credit for some validations.

Anyone has any idea why the Spree::User.credit is not being updated?

Comment: States are defined in `Spree::Order::Checkout` and I had to add decorator for that module to get it working - strange, I'm pretty sure it worked like you wrote in question.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your logs it's tough to say, but I'm guessing you haven't whitelisted the credit params. If that's the case you can add this to initializers/spree.rb

```
Spree::PermittedAttributes.user_attributes << :credit
```

If not, could you post your server log for the update action?

Comment: Since Spree logs can get quite lengthy I wouldn't know what to include. Still, if I'm correct the whitelisted parameters are to allow information to controllers. In any way I've whitelisted the credit attribute, but on the order itself. This has been used to create the adjustment, so I know it's working. Also on the logs there is no 'Unpermitted Parameter'  alert and no failed Insert, which makes me think that the action is not failing but is never being executed.

Comment: You need to include the POST request and params from right after you update the order.